# SQL Query to accept time difference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

We have SSIS job that inserts records into two tables. When I see the InsertDate, there is some 10 to 20 milliseconds time difference.

I need to compare two Tables based on InsertDate but when comparing it should ignore if the difference is less than 60 seconds.

```
Ex: 
2017-03-15 06:09:59.930
2017-03-15 06:10:50.030

Select * from A
inner join B
on A.ID = B.ID
Where A.insertdate < B.inserdate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`DATEDIFF` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) supported since SQL Server 2008:

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

Making your query:

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B
  ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE DATEDIFF(second, A.insertdate, B.insertdate) < 60
```

The `second` argument calculates the difference between the two dates in seconds. Given the check of `DATEDIFF(...) < 60`, there can be one of the 3 following scenarios:

1. The `DATEDIFF` function is **negative**: This means that `A.insertdate` is less than `B.insertdate`
2. The `DATEDIFF` function is **zero**: This means that `A.insertdate` is equal to `B.insertdate`
3. The `DATEDIFF` function is **between 1-60**: means that `A.insertdate` is upto 60 seconds larger than `B.insertdate`

Effectively, you could change the check against the `DATEDIFF` function based on your specific needs, such as: checking that `DATEDIFF(...)` is between -60 and 0 ensures that `A.insertdate` is upto 60 seconds earlier than `B.insertdate` but not more.

Note: An earlier version of the question had a join condition of `A.insertdate = B.insertdate` resulting in a `DATEDIFF` expression of `DATEDIFF(second, A.insertdate, B.insertdate) BETWEEN -60 AND 60`.

Comment: I like this one better than my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is that possible to check the same condition in where clause.
Ex : 
Select * from A
inner join B
where A.Inserdate > B.insertdate

Comment: @Ask_SO - I've updated the answer based on your revised query in the question, which has `WHERE A.insertdate < B.insertdate`

Answer (score 2):

You can round up the datetime before JOINing them:

```
SELECT *
FROM   A
JOIN   B
    ON CAST(A.insertdate AS smalldatetime) =
       CAST(B.insertdate AS smalldatetime)
```